# How to build a segment tree without recursion?

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, tree, segment-tree

I'm trying to understand the process of building a [segment tree](https://cp-algorithms.com/data_structures/segment_tree.html) using Python. I've come up with a function like this (which works):

```
arr = [ ... ]
tree = [None] * (4*len(arr))

def build(v, vl, vr):
    if vl == vr:
        tree[v] = arr[vl]
        return

    vm = (vl + vr) // 2
    build(2*v + 1, vl, vm)
    build(2*v + 2, vm + 1, vr)
    tree[v] = tree[2*v + 1] + tree[2*v + 2]

build(0, 0, len(arr) - 1)
```

How can I make this build function iterative (w/o recursion)? Also, what's the time complexity of building a segment tree this way? Some tutorials state that it's `O(n)`, but don't the recursive calls make it `O(n*log(n))`?

Comment: If the code works, I think this is could be asked in [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: What is `arr = [ ... ]` ?

Comment: [Builds a segment Tree without recursion](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/segment-tree-efficient-implementation/)

Comment: `arr` is the original array from which the segment tree is built.

Comment: It seems that you suffer from an irrational "fear" of recursion.

Comment: [Efficient and easy segment trees - Codeforces](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/18051)